# Entity Framework - counting entries

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Adding pagination to a (dotnet EntityFramework  Core) table of db entities, I'd like to show a message like 'Showing items X to Y of Z' where Z is the total number of items in the table being paged.

Currently I fetch that total number of entries from a `DbSet` in a `DbContext` as `dbContext.Things.Count()`.

On the plus side, this works (modulo possible ongoing parallel updates to the table of `Things`, but that's close enough for me).

On the down side, I'm concerned that it might not be particularly efficient, even that it might try to load items into memory. Clearly, with pagination I will need to load only a handful of items to display the current page.

My database is postgresql 9.5, accessed via Npsql.

So my **question** is: does anyone know of any pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: `Count()` should be evaluated server side (SQL). If you are not sure what's going on, turn EF Core logging on and you'll see the executed queries.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look in conjunction with some of the other options I have added below.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's `SELECT COUNT(*)::INT4 FROM "Things" AS "t"` which per the link in my answer "can be rather slow".  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. At least this proves that it doesn't load all the records into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that for Postgres, `Count` could be an `O(n)` operation after all... https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

There are tricks to try [here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#dup_counts_exact) which involve executing SQL at a penalty of producing estimates and/or slowing writes.

This table of mine is written far more often than it is read, so a naïve `Count` will do for the time being.